# How do I loop through a set of numbers, do some addition and append to an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, while-loop, append

My goal here is to create an array with the sum totals of every combination of 2 numbers on a set of dice. I'm creating the beginning of a loop that adds `die1[0]` to `die2[0..5]` before going through `die1[1] + die2[0..5]` and so on.

I've got this code below and I'm doing something wrong. I want to be able to call specific numbers in the array, such as `dieSums[4]`, and get one number. Any idea what i'm doing incorrectly here?

```
die1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
die2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

dieSums = []

count = 0
while count <= 5 do   
  dieSums << die1[0] + die2[count]   
  count += 1   
  puts dieSums[5]    
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `puts dieSums[5]` inside the loop. `dieSums[5]` won't exist until the last iteration. It'll work if you call it outside the loop:

```
die1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
die2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

dieSums = []

count = 0
while count <= 5 do   
  dieSums << die1[0] + die2[count]   
  count += 1
end

puts dieSums[5] #=> 7
```

Answer (score 4):

A `while` loop, as you've written it, isn't very Rubyonic. (Rubinic?) A more idiomatic way to iterate over the elements of an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

die1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
die2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

dieSums = []

die1.each do |d1|
    die2.each do |d2|
        dieSums << d1 + d2
    end
end
puts dieSums[5]
```

Of course, `die1` and `die2` are identical in this case, so you could replace `die2` with `die1` and it'd all work out.

Comment: I'm a noob. I'm not there yet but thanks for the insight about how to write clean ruby!

Comment: Indenting with 4 spaces (or tabs?) is not very ruby-esque neither ;)

Comment: @d11wtq, hehe, that's correct, but I can't stand two-space-indents: the difference in nesting is too subtle. I stick to two spaces when I'm working on projects that already have two spaces, but I grumble all the while.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note: notice that you are over-complicating the problem (because you think in imperative terms, take a look at [Functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)). The sum of all possible values for two dice:

```
>> die = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>> die.product(die).map { |v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

- Call `uniq` at the end if you don't want repeated values.
- Use `repeated_combination(2)` instead of `product` if you don't care about the order.
- Note that `die.product(die)` = `die.repeated_permutation(2)`)

Finding all the sums for N dice is almost as simple:

```
>> die.repeated_permutation(5).map { |values| values.inject(:+) }
```

Comment: I kept looking for a mechanism to do list comprehensions in Ruby but thought most of the mechanisms looked pretty gross. _This_ is pretty nearly optimum given that Ruby doesn't support simpler list comprehensions.